# NUnit custom reporting via Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit, reporting

I would like to integrate TestRail with NUnit. The basic idea would be to use the [Property] attribute to assign TestRail Case IDs to test methods and then use an ITestEventListener to perform live updates on TestRail while the test suite is running.

For that purpose I created a project in my solution with the implementation of said interface and the [Extension] attribute:

```
[Extension(Description = "TestRail Integration", EngineVersion = "3.4")]
public class TestRailIntegration : ITestEventListener
{
    public void OnTestEvent(string report)
    {
        var path = Path.Combine("D:\\NUnit", "foobar.txt");

        if (!Directory.Exists("D:\\NUnit"))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory("D:\\NUnit");
        }

        File.WriteAllText(path, report);
    }
}
```

But how do I get NUnit to actually use that extension? I have two use cases: running from Visual Studio and running via TeamCity. I've read about ".addins" files, but creating one in my project (which is then copied with my TestSuite.dll and nunit.engine.dll to the output directory) seems to have no effect.

Where do I have to place the ".addins" file? I run all tests from within VS (with Resharper)

Answer (score 0):

Every runner that supports engine extensions (not all do) should come with an `.addins` file in the same directory as `nunit.engine.dll`. That file may point to a list of files and/or to a directory.

If a directory is pointed to, that directory may contain other `.addins` files, allowing them to be chained.

Usually, your best bet is to put your extension in a directory together with it's own `.addins` file and add that directory to your primary `.addins` file. That way, you can use xcopy deployment and only need to edit one file.

Bear in mind that any extension that is installed in multiple ways (zip, msi, nuget) will probably need a different `.addins` file for each of those package types. If you look closely at the NUnit engine itself, you'll see that's what we do.

Comment: Thanks, that already helps a lot! I have changed my approach a little: I will simply use NUnit without the extension to develop and debug my test cases via Visual Studio and then use my test event listener on the build server.